# Unable to log egress traffic HTTP requests with the istio-proxy

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

I am following [this guide](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#access-an-external-https-service).

Ingress requests are getting logged. Egress traffic control is working as expected, except I am unable to log egress HTTP requests. What is missing?

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: myapp

  outboundTrafficPolicy:
    mode: REGISTRY_ONLY

  egress:
    - hosts:
        - default/*.example.com
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: example

spec:
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: NONE
  hosts:
    - '*.example.com'

  ports:
    - name: https
      protocol: TLS
      number: 443
```

```yaml
apiVersion: telemetry.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Telemetry
metadata:
  name: mesh-default
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  accessLogging:
    - providers:
        - name: envoy
```

Kubernetes 1.22.2 Istio 1.11.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ingress traffic logging I am using `EnvoyFilter` to set log format and it is working without any additional configuration. In the egress case, I had to set `accessLogFile: /dev/stdout`.

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: config
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  profile: default
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK istio collects only ingress HTTP logs by default.

In the istio documentation there is an [old article](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2018/egress-monitoring-access-control/#summary) (from 2018) describing how to enable egress traffic HTTP logs.

Please keep in mind that some of the information may be outdated, however I believe this is the part that you are missing.

Comment: I have already tried this. And it looks like deprecated: `no matches for kind "logentry" in version "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"`